# Complex jQuery and SVG interactions

Tags: jquery, css, svg

I have a very complex svg that I am trying to get to play nicely with jQuery. Basically I am trying to introduce a hover and click state on the various petals, where the outcome will be different depending on which one I've interacted with. My svg looks like;

```
<svg version="1.1" id="run-compare-graph"  style="margin-top:-30px;height:400px;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 356.2 356.5" enable-background="new 0 0 356.2 356.5" xml:space="preserve">

                    <g id="mask_1" class="card-toggle">
                        <path fill="#BDBDBD" d="M52.2,52.3"/>
                        <path fill="#BDBDBD" d="M0,178.3"/>
                        <path fill="#BDBDBD" d="M52.2,304.3"/>
                        <path fill="#BDBDBD" d="M178.2,356.5"/>
                        <path fill="#BDBDBD" d="M304.1,304.3"/>
                        <path fill="#BDBDBD" d="M356.3,178.3"/>
                        <g>
                            <defs>
                                <polyline id="SVGID_1_" points="304.1,52.3 178.2,0.1 178,178.3          "/>
                            </defs>
                            <clipPath id="SVGID_2_">
                                <use xlink:href="#SVGID_1_"  overflow="visible"/>
                            </clipPath>
                            <circle clip-path="url(#SVGID_2_)" fill="#57D6AC" cx="178" cy="178.3" r="149"/>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                    <g id="mask_2" class="card-toggle">
                        <path fill="#BDBDBD" d="M52.2,52.3"/>
                        <path fill="#BDBDBD" d="M0,178.3"/>
                        <path fill="#BDBDBD" d="M52.2,304.3"/>
                        <path fill="#BDBDBD" d="M178.2,356.5"/>
                        <path fill="#BDBDBD" d="M304.1,304.3"/>
                        <path fill="#BDBDBD" d="M356.3,178.3"/>
                        <g>
                            <defs>
                                <polyline id="SVGID_3_" points="356.3,178.4 304.1,52.4 178,178.3            "/>
                            </defs>
                            <clipPath id="SVGID_4_">
                                <use xlink:href="#SVGID_3_"  overflow="visible"/>
                            </clipPath>
                            <circle clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#F1F954" cx="177.7" cy="178.8" r="101"/>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                    <g id="mask_3" class="card-toggle">
                        <g>
                            <defs>
                                <polyline id="SVGID_5_" points="304,304.4 356.2,178.5 178,178.3             "/>
                            </defs>
                            <clipPath id="SVGID_6_">
                                <use xlink:href="#SVGID_5_"  overflow="visible"/>
                            </clipPath>
                            <circle clip-path="url(#SVGID_6_)" fill="#6B6565" cx="177.7" cy="178.5" r="112"/>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                    <g id="mask_4" class="card-toggle">
                        <g>
                            <defs>
                                <polyline id="SVGID_7_" points="177.9,356.6 303.9,304.4 178,178.3           "/>
                            </defs>
                            <clipPath id="SVGID_8_">
                                <use xlink:href="#SVGID_7_"  overflow="visible"/>
                            </clipPath>
                            <circle clip-path="url(#SVGID_8_)" fill="#0F5947" cx="178.3" cy="178.3" r="109"/>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                    <g id="mask_5" class="card-toggle">
                        <g>
                            <defs>
                                <polyline id="SVGID_9_" points="51.9,304.3 177.8,356.5 178,178.3            "/>
                            </defs>
                            <clipPath id="SVGID_10_">
                                <use xlink:href="#SVGID_9_"  overflow="visible"/>
                            </clipPath>
                            <circle clip-path="url(#SVGID_10_)" fill="#57D6AC" cx="178" cy="178.3" r="101"/>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                    <g id="mask_6" class="card-toggle">
                        <g>
                            <defs>
                                <polyline id="SVGID_11_" points="-0.3,178.2 51.9,304.1 178,178.3            "/>
                            </defs>
                            <clipPath id="SVGID_12_">
                                <use xlink:href="#SVGID_11_"  overflow="visible"/>
                            </clipPath>
                            <circle clip-path="url(#SVGID_12_)" fill="#0F5947" cx="178" cy="178.3" r="111"/>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                    <g id="mask_7" class="card-toggle">
                        <g>
                            <defs>
                                <polyline id="SVGID_13_" points="52,52.1 -0.2,178.1 178,178.3           "/>
                            </defs>
                            <clipPath id="SVGID_14_">
                                <use xlink:href="#SVGID_13_"  overflow="visible"/>
                            </clipPath>
                            <circle clip-path="url(#SVGID_14_)" fill="#57D6AC" cx="178" cy="178.3" r="93"/>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                    <g id="mask_8" class="card-toggle">
                        <g>
                            <defs>
                                <polyline id="SVGID_15_" points="178.1,0 52.1,52.2 178,178.3            "/>
                            </defs>
                            <clipPath id="SVGID_16_">
                                <use xlink:href="#SVGID_15_"  overflow="visible"/>
                            </clipPath>
                            <circle clip-path="url(#SVGID_16_)" fill="#F1F954" cx="177.9" cy="178.2" r="101"/>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                    <g id="Layer_5">
                        <circle fill="#414045" cx="178.2" cy="178.4" r="63"/>
                        <circle opacity="0.3" fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="178.2" cy="178.3" r="100.7"/>
                        <circle opacity="0.3" fill="#414045" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="178.2" cy="178.3" r="81.3"/>
                    </g>
                    <g id="RUN_SCORE">
                        <text transform="matrix(1.0008 0 0 1 145.7867 148.506)" fill="#BDBDBD" font-size="12.147">RUN SCORE</text>
                    </g>
                    <g id="_x36_7">

                            <text id="run-compare-value"  transform="matrix(1.0008 0 0 1 136.7773 210.2179)" fill="#57D6AC" font-size="67.0697" letter-spacing="-1"><span class="runcompare odometer lime-text">98</span></text>
                    </g>
                    </svg>
```

where the output looks like this:

[image]

I am now trying to implement some jQuery action like click and hover states over the various petals. The best I could do was to target the circles using

```
$('svg .card-toggle').mouseover(function(){
  $('.data-card').eq($(this).index()).addClass("big");
});
```

This works well-ish... However it breaks down close to the edges of where the colors change, and close to the center of the circle.

**QUESTION:**
Do I need to rework how I am using the jQuery? Or am I 'SOL' as they say, because this is the best markup I am going to get, given the shape I am trying to reproduce?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: You might be a little SOL here. You might wanna try http://snapsvg.io/ to see if that framework gives you more control.

Comment: Maybe you should put the bits on a fiddle and explain what specifically isn't working or whatever. I too would maybe think about using Raphael (if you need older browser support), or Snap or something else, but it could also be overkill.

Comment: So, just as an update. I found that the parts of the graph that weren't responding to my mouseover event were because they were being masked by other parts of the svg. A simple pointer-events:none was added to the masking layers and it has been fixed:)

Comment: I don't have code to share but what I've done in the past is to rewrite jQuery to work with SVG. It's a lot of work but worth the effort.